# Iterating through JSonArray response from url using android volley

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-volley, android-json

**This is my JSonArray**

```
{  
   "vendor":[  
      {  
         "vendor_name":"Tapan Moharana",
         "vendor_description":"",
         "vendor_slug":"tapan",
         "vendor_logo":null,
         "contact_number":null
      }
   ],
   "products":[  
      {  
         "name":"Massage",
         "price":"5000.0000",
         "image":"http:\/\/carrottech.com\/lcart\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/1\/image\/150x\/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95\/2\/9\/29660571-beauty-spa-woman-portrait-beautiful-girl-touching-her-face.jpg"
      },
      {  
         "name":"Chicken Chilly",
         "price":"234.0000",
         "image":"http:\/\/carrottech.com\/lcart\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/1\/image\/150x\/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95\/c\/h\/cheicken.jpg"
      },
      {  
         "name":"Chicken Biryani",
         "price":"500.0000",
         "image":"http:\/\/carrottech.com\/lcart\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/1\/image\/150x\/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95\/placeholder\/default\/image_1.jpg"
      }
   ]
}
```

**and this is my java code:**

```
    JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONArray children = jsono.getJSONArray("vendor");
    JSONArray childrenProducts = jsono.getJSONArray("products");
    for (int i = 0; i <children.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonData = children.getJSONObject(i);
        System.out.print(jsonData.getString("vendor_name") + "<----");
        //  String vendorThumbNailURL=jsonData.getString("")
        //jvendorImageURL.setImageUrl(local, mImageLoader);
        vendorLogo=vendorLogo+jsonData.getString("vendor_logo").trim();
        jvendorImageURL.setImageUrl(vendorLogo, mImageLoader);
        jvendorName.setText(jsonData.getString("vendor_name"));
        jvendorAbout.setText(jsonData.getString("vendor_description"));
        jvendorContact.setText(jsonData.getString("contact_number"));
        System.out.print(jsonData.getString("products") + "<----");
    }
    for(int i=0;i<childrenProducts.length();i++){
        JSONObject jsonData = childrenProducts.getJSONObject(i);
        System.out.println("inside products");
        System.out.print(jsonData.getString("name") + "<----dd");
    }
```

The first for loop is working fine but the second forloop is not.. i dont get anything if i try to execute those print statements inside the second for loop.. please help me!!

Comment: In your response children has only one item means children size is 1, thats why it is iterating only onse..

Comment: I have made a separate object: JSONArray childrenProducts = jsono.getJSONArray("products");  this is the second array it is odd that this code is nt working..

Comment: What value you are getting for childrenProducts.length()??

Comment: 4 is what i am getting when i print childrenProducts.length()

Comment: According to your response length should be 3..
Are you getting data in jsonData?

Comment: Did you try using `Log.i("MY TAG", jsonData.getString("name"));` instead of `System.out.print` ?

Comment: yea it should be 3.. @vucko i am trying tht right now give me a min

Comment: IT DOESNT GO INSIDE THE SECOND FOR LOOP!!! :'(

Comment: is your application crashes???

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [Gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) to get parse the JSON string simply?

You need to declares classes first to match the JSON response like this.

```
public class Vendor {

    private String vendor_name;
    private String vendor_description;
    private String vendor_slug;
    private String vendor_logo;
    private String contact_number;

    public Vendor() {
    }

    public String getVendor_name() {
        return vendor_name;
    }

    public String getVendor_description() {
        return vendor_description;
    }

    public String getVendor_slug() {
        return vendor_slug;
    }

    public String getVendor_logo() {
        return vendor_logo;
    }

    public String getContact_number() {
        return contact_number;
    }
}
```

...

```
public class Product {

    private String name;
    private String price;
    private String image;

    public Product() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }
}
```

Now declare the `Response` class like this

```
public class Response {

    private List<Vendor> vendor;
    private List<Product> products;

    public Response() {
    }

    public List<Vendor> getVendor() {
        return vendor;
    }

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }
}
```

Now, once you've the JSON string its easy to bounce the data using GSON into the `Response` class like this.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Response mResponse = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Response.class);
```

Simple!

Comment: If it first prints the data atleast then i can proceed with what you said but it isnt printing the data at all..

Comment: You've the json string right? You can go with this procedure anyway. There might be a problem with your loop or parsing. Let GSON to do the parsing for you. You'll just get the values from `mResponse` class and then try printing them. Its easy to use and I almost wrote the full code for you.

Answer (score 1):

**It is not going in your second for loop because there is  `SomeException` in your first for loop.**

Your execution will be thrown out to any `catch()` clause, and the further execution will not be done including your second for loop.

Just try putting that up like this:

```
    JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONArray children = jsono.getJSONArray("vendor");
    JSONArray childrenProducts = jsono.getJSONArray("products");

    //this will be executed now..!!

    for(int i=0;i<childrenProducts.length();i++){
        JSONObject jsonData = childrenProducts.getJSONObject(i);
        System.out.println("inside products");
        System.out.print(jsonData.getString("name") + "<----dd");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <children.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonData = children.getJSONObject(i);
        System.out.print(jsonData.getString("vendor_name") + "<----");
        //  String vendorThumbNailURL=jsonData.getString("")
        //jvendorImageURL.setImageUrl(local, mImageLoader);
        vendorLogo=vendorLogo+jsonData.getString("vendor_logo").trim();
        jvendorImageURL.setImageUrl(vendorLogo, mImageLoader);
        jvendorName.setText(jsonData.getString("vendor_name"));
        jvendorAbout.setText(jsonData.getString("vendor_description"));
        jvendorContact.setText(jsonData.getString("contact_number"));
        System.out.print(jsonData.getString("products") + "<----");
    }
```

Comment: it wasn't working even when vendor had a value but i think it was maybe because of some exception

Comment: exactly.. This will work if you don't put two try.. catch..!!

Comment: I have edited to be correct..!! This was the actual problem.. please accept it if it explains the same issue..!!

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved it:

```
   try {
                    JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray children = jsono.getJSONArray("vendor");
                    for (int i = 0; i <children.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonData = children.getJSONObject(i);
                        System.out.print(jsonData.getString("vendor_name") + "<----");
                      //  String vendorThumbNailURL=jsonData.getString("")
                        //jvendorImageURL.setImageUrl(local, mImageLoader);
                        vendorLogo=vendorLogo+jsonData.getString("vendor_logo").trim();
                        jvendorImageURL.setImageUrl(vendorLogo, mImageLoader);
                        jvendorName.setText(jsonData.getString("vendor_name"));
                        jvendorAbout.setText(jsonData.getString("vendor_description"));
                        jvendorContact.setText(jsonData.getString("contact_number"));
                        System.out.print(jsonData.getString("products") + "<----");
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray childrenProducts = jsono.getJSONArray("products");
                    System.out.println(childrenProducts.length()+"LENGTH");
                    for(int i=0; i<childrenProducts.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject jsonData1 = childrenProducts.getJSONObject(i);
                        System.out.println(childrenProducts.length() + "LENGTH");
                        System.out.print(jsonData1.getString("name") + "<----dd");
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

just had to take two separate try blocks... can someone please tell why was it not working in one try block? the above code works